# Conditional statements in foobar2000 sort syntax

Tags: music, metadata, tags, foobar2000, music-management

My music files are tagged with some custom tags, which for some reason aren't entirely standardized. This is probably due to some peculiarity with my [MusicBrainz Picard](https://picard.musicbrainz.org/) set-up, but that is beside the point.

Anyway, when sorting by tags that should be equivalent, I would like each track to be sorted by the one tag it actually has. My approach is:

```
$if3(%albumartistsortorder%, %albumartistsort%) $if3(%original release date%, %date%) %album% %disc% %track%
```

What appears to happen instead is that the sort just ignores the conditions and reads the tag fields (including the parameters) as if there were no `$if3()` there.

A second approach is to write my own field remappings. According to [this guide](http://brother-john.net/tagz/tagz-intro.html#fieldremap), the `%artist%` field is actually short for

```
$if3($meta(artist),$meta(album artist),$meta(composer),$meta(performer))
```

If I could define my own mappings like this, this would solve my problem. Is this possible, or what else can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, conditional statements work just fine in sort strings. However, `$if3()` should have its arguments separated with commas and nothing else. Using spaces caused various confusing problems. A working sort string is:

```
$if3(%albumartistsortorder%,%albumartistsort%,%artistsortorder%,%album artist%) $if3(%original release date%,%date%) %album% %disc% %track%
```

This is the same string as the one in the question, with proper syntax. It also uses `%artistsortorder%` and `%album artist%` as fallback fields for where there is no sorted album artist.